# Add autocomplete to Typescript/React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a component (typescript + react) which I published on NPM. I want to make IntelliSense autocomplete React props for this component for me. For plain react components I used js doc, but it doesn't work here.

example of component:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component<
  MyCompPropsInterface,
  MyCompComponentState
  > {...}
```

index file

```
 import { MyComp } from './components/MyComp ';

 export { MyComp };
```

If I missed something please point it and I will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem, I didn't pass my interface to the constructor.

How it should be:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component<
 MyCompPropsInterface,
 MyCompComponentState
 > {
constructor(
   public props: ImagePropsInterface,
 ) 
}
```